# Existence of a solution for a quasilinear hyperbolic system of PDEs with many state variables

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

I'll star by saying that I am not really familiar with the field of PDEs so this questions may be trivial or ill-possed in that case please let me know.

I am  in search of some existence (Global) result regarding a system of first order PDEs with many state-variables and a non-homogeneity that is non-linear in the solutions, i.e.

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \mathbf u+\sum_{n=1}^{K} A_n(t)\partial_{x_n} \mathbf u=\mathbf b(t,\mathbf u,x_1,\cdots,x_K)\\
\mathbf u(0,x_1,\cdots,x_K)=u_0\in\mathbb R^N,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where the matrices $A_n, n=1,\cdots, K$ are diagonal, and $\mathbf b$ is Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbf u$ uniformly in $t,x_1,\cdots,x_n$.

In Bressan's "Conservations laws" book the case with two variables is considered, namely $t$ and $x$. I have found some articles online considering the case with many state variables but in that case the non-homogeneity was linear in the $\mathbf u$ .

As far as I know the method of the characteristics applies only the one-dimensional case, so I am a little bit lost.

Is there some result I can use to show the existence (and uniqueness if possible) of a solution for this system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the standard **local** existence result for your system would require higher regularity for $\mathbf{b}$. Your equation is automatically symmetric hyperbolic, and so Kato's result (1975, ARMA) can apply, _provided that $\mathbf{b}$ is continuously differentiable $\lfloor K/2\rfloor + 1$ times_.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong,  well asking for more regularity on $b$ is not an issue, what worries me is the local character of the result. Still do you have the complete name of Kato's article/book? I don't find it

Comment: @WillieWong I was wondering, since the matrices $A$ are diagonal,  isn't there a way to apply the method of the characteristics? The equations are not uncouples since $b$ depends on all the solutions of course

Comment: The method of characteristics for first order scalar PDEs approaches by finding a foliation of the domain by hypersurfaces on which the solution is constant. Even though $A$ is diagonal, the corresponding foliations are different for different components of $\mathbf{u}$, and thus in general they are not compatible and cannot be reassembled to a coupled equation.

Comment: Kato's paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00280740. For the "global" problem: if you let me know more precisely what can be assumed about $\mathbf{b}$, I may be able to help you with it. But there is unlikely any general thing you can say about it; results about global existence of hyperbolic systems typically are very structure dependent.

Comment: @WillieWong thank you so much for the comments, I asked that because I've received an answer (on a related question) saying that if the equations on the system were coupled just through the non-homegeneity $b$ (as in my question above) then the method of characteristics could be applied. Tomorrow I'll give you more information regarding the function $b$. Thanks again!

Comment: @WillieWong so we can assume that $\mathbf b=(b_1,\cdots,b_N)$ (each component) is continuous differentiable w.r.t $\mathbf u$ as many times as needed with bounded first derivatives; it's linear in $x_i, i=1,\cdots, K$; it's a rapidly decreasing function in $t$.

Comment: @WillieWong more in particular $b_i(\cdots)= c_i(\mathbf u)+\sum_{n=1}^K \xi_n(t)x_n$ where $c_i$ is continuous differentiable as many times as needed, and $\xi_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite function

Comment: Standard energy based techniques, applied naively, won't help then, because your $b_i$ is unbounded due to the linear dependence on $x$.

Comment: @WillieWong what a shame! I hope Kato's result could still be applied. Thanks a lot for the feedback!

Comment: @WillieWong Still, there's a way in which I can get rid of the linear part, and we may assume as well that $c$ will depend on $u$ and $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and it's bounded and continuously differentiable as many times as needed. Can I do something in that case?

Comment: Wait, hang-on: your $A_n$ are actually diagonal, not just block diagonal? And they are real-valued, right? I seem to have been overthinking your problem because I thought it is more general. So what you have is a coupled system of transport equations; then you don't need Kato.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, the $A_n$ are actually diagonal, and depend only on $t$. The equations are coupled just through the function $\mathbf b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I would write your equations instead in the following form:
$$ \partial_t u_i + v_i(t) \cdot \nabla u_i = b_i (t, \vec{x}, \vec{u}) $$
This is a system of transport equations and so can actually be solved by using a variation of the Picard-Lindelof argument.

(I am implicitly assuming that your function $b$ is suitably nice in certain ways, which are implied by what you said is allowed in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377821/existence-of-a-solution-for-a-quasilinear-hyperbolic-system-of-pdes-with-many-st?noredirect=1#comment958928_377821).)

### 1

Consider the iteration scheme
$$ \vec{w} \mapsto \vec{w}' $$
where $\vec{v}'$ solves the linear inhomogeneous equation
$$ \partial_t w'_i + v_i(t) \cdot \nabla w'_i = b_i(t,\vec{x}, \vec{w})$$
with the *fixed*, given, initial data $\mathring{\vec{w}}:\mathbb{R}^K\to \mathbb{R}^N$.

Given a continuous function $\vec{w}: [-t_0, t_0] \times\mathbb{R}^K \to \mathbb{R}^N$, the function $\vec{w}'$ can be solved component wise by integrating along the integral curves of $\partial_t + v_i(t) \cdot \nabla$ on $[-t_0, t_0]\times \mathbb{R}^K$.

It thus suffices to show that this iteration scheme converges.

### 2

Suppose $\vec{z}$ and $\vec{w}$ are given functions that are uniformly bounded by some constant $M$. Then there exists (under what I hope are reasonable assumptions on $b_i$) some constant $M'$ such that $b_i(t,\vec{x},\vec{z})$ and $b_i(t,\vec{x},\vec{w})$ are uniformly bounded by $M'$. Thus you have that

$$ | \vec{z}'|_\infty, |\vec{w}'|_\infty \leq |\mathring{\vec{w}}|_\infty + M' t_0 $$

Choose $M = 2 |\mathring{\vec{w}}|_\infty$ and there exists some $t_0 > 0$ such that the iteration mapping maps the (closed) ball of radius $M$ in $C^0([-t_0, t_0]\times \mathbb{R}^K,\mathbb{R}^N)$ to itself.

### 3

For the differences you find that
$$ \partial_t (z'_i - w'_i) + v_i(t)\cdot \nabla (z'_i - w'_i) = b_i(t,\vec{x}, \vec{z}) - b_i(t,\vec{x},\vec{w}) $$
Using the Lipschitz continuity in the final slot of $b_i$ you get that
$$ \big|\partial_t (z'_i - w'_i) + v_i(t)\cdot \nabla (z'_i - w'_i) \big| \leq M'' |\vec{z} - \vec{w}| $$
for some $M''$. Integrating you get that if $t_0$ is chosen sufficiently small, the iteration mapping is a contraction mapping.

### 4

Applying Banach fixed-point theorem you get local existence.

### 5

Having proven local existence, you can upgrade this to global in the same way you argue for ODEs: by showing that the sup norm of the functions involved does not blow-up. This follows from the *global* Lipschitz property of the functions $b_i$, which guarantees that $|b_i(t,\vec{x},\vec{w})| \leq M''' (1 + |\vec{w}|)$

So a standard Gronwall's inequality argument well tell you that the sup-norm of the solution cannot grow faster than $A e^{2 M''' |t|}$ for some constant $A$.

Comment: thank you so much Willie! This is really helpful

Comment: +1 Willie Wong and @Chaos: I like the analysis of the posed problem you did, up to get the final, optimal solution. In sum, really a nice piece of real research mathematics.

Comment: Ey Willie sorry for bothering you again, in the last step, how can I apply the Gronwall inequality? I am not familiar with the application to PDEs.

Comment: THe differential inequality, after integration, gives $$|\vec{w}(t)|_{\infty} \leq |\vec{w}(0)|_{\infty} + \int_0^t M'''(1 + |\vec{w}(s)|_{\infty} ~ds$$ Add 1 to both side and apply Gronwall to the quantity $1 + |\vec{w}(t)|_\infty$.

Comment: Why do we end up integrating wrt to $t$ alone, what about the $\vec{x}$? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I know very little about this stuff.

Comment: $| \text{---} |_\infty$ is the supermum norm in $x$. That is, for continuous functions we are setting  $|f|_\infty = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^K} |f(x)|$.